# Getting "No module named" error

Tags: python, django

EDIT: I do have `__init__.py` It was generated when django made the app. I'm just adding a file in the directory. The script is just trying to `from npage.models import Page, Level, Section, Edge` but it cannot do it for some odd reason or another :(

EDIT 2: Directory Structure + Code Snippet:

```
└── npage/ <-- My package?
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__/
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
    │   └── models.cpython-34.pyc
    ├── admin.py
    ├── forms.py
    ├── middleware.py
    ├── mixins.py
    ├── models.py <-- My module?
    ├── restructure.py <-- from package.module import classes (Edge,Page, etc.)
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

Code snippet from `restructure.py`,

```
from npage.models import Edge
import MySQLdb

def ordered_pages_for(level):
    """ return sorted list of pages represented as dictionary objects """
    # the rest of the code just converts a linked list of pages into an Edge set and a table of Pages
# ...
def build_edge_table_of_pages(pagedicts_in_order):
    # prev and next are Page instances (None, 4) where 4 is the first page.pk
    prev0 = None
    for pd in pagedicts_in_order:
        # make a page next=page(pd)
        next0 = page(pd)
        # add an edge prev<-->next    (prev will be None at first)
        e = Edge.create(prev = prev0, next = next0)
        e.save()
        # save prev = next    (now prev is not None, it's a Page.)
        prev0 = next0
    # make edge prev<-->None
    e = Edge.create(prev = prev0, next = None)
    e.save()
```

I wrote a script to import a database table into a new django model defined structure...

I placed the script inside an app called 'npage'. `views.py` contains `from npage.models import *` and it is working fine. I have the same line in my script which is in the same directory and it is saying there is not nodule named npage. What am I missing here?

```
(env)glitch:npage nathann$ python restructure.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "restructure.py", line 32, in <module>
    from npage.models import * # whhhyyy???
ImportError: No module named npage.models
```

I tried doing a relative import and it gave me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "restructure.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .models import * # whhhyyy???
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Comment: is there an `__init__.py` file in the directory? it says its a `non-package`; to make it one put a blank file named `__init__.py` in the dir.

Comment: Yep! `npage/__init__.py` and all my models, views and urls are in there importing happily away. but `restructure.py` is not importing, yet it is in the same directory... :/

Comment: Are there any files with the name npage.py? Also, have you tried removing any pyc files in your path?

Comment: no. only a directory npage. Why would it throw `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package` if I am in a package? (I have `__init__.py`) I tried deleting all my pyc and running again. same error.

Comment: could you post the directory structure and a code snippet?

Comment: What imports do you have in models.py?

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue. It was simple.

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "ipals.settings")

# And abracadabra I can import everything now.
from npage.models import Page, Edge, Level
```

Where `ipals` is the name of my project. I had to do this so it recognized my `npage` app. Please comment on this answer so I can edit and expound on why this works. From my perspective I simple had an environment issue. My script was executing within the wrong context.